# How to use co_await operator in C++ the simpliest way?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, async-await, c++20, c++-coroutine

What is the minimum set of actions I should do to use C++ `co_await` operator like C# `await` operator?

There is an [article on cppreferense](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines) about corutines, where there is C# like class `task<>` which is used as return type, but I can't find it in standard library. When function return void, this predictably leads to a compile error.

Comment: The C++ standard library does not contain any substantial types that represent coroutines. That is, there is no equivalent to `task`. So while the language supports them, you have to build the machinery yourself; that's the "minimum set of actions" you need.

Comment: Unlike C#, which has a language-defined coroutine implementation ([Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task)), C++'s `co_await` is a building block that you can build coroutines on top of. Many people have written coroutine libraries on top of `co_await`, each with different characteristics. Some use hot-start, some lazy-start. Some honor COM threading, others are thread-agnostic. Unlike C#, which has a point of view (hot-start, COM-honoring), C++ leaves it to each library to decide what its policies are.

Answer (score 1):

`task` in that case is just a placeholder for the plumbing you put together yourself.

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines

> Every coroutine must have a return type that satisfies a number of requirements

When you use `co_*` in your code you need to `#include <coroutine>`. The compiler will do stuff to your function. Example:

```cpp
void csp_await() {
  bidirectional_channel<int> ch;

  co_await ch.send(1);
}
```

The above code results in the following error:

> class "std::coroutine_traits" has no member "promise_type"

Whatever the compiler is doing, it is looking for a `promise_type` but it cannot find it.

To get past this we need to introduce the following code.

```cpp
struct task_handle {};

struct task : std::coroutine_handle<task_handle> {
  using promise_type = task_handle;
};
```

The return type of the `csp_await` function is changed to use our `task` type which results in a different error:

> "task::promise_type" has no member "initial_suspend"

So we add some more stuff

```cpp
struct task_handle;

struct task : std::coroutine_handle<task_handle> {
  using promise_type = task_handle;
};

struct task_handle {
  task                get_return_object() { return {task::from_promise(*this)}; }
  std::suspend_always initial_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
  std::suspend_always final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
  void                return_void() {}
  void                unhandled_exception() {}
};
```

The next thing to do is to make the `send` function of the `bidirectional_channel` coroutine friendly. It is currently a blocking function with the return type `void` which cannot be used as is.

```cpp
template <typename T> struct send_async_awaiter {
  bidirectional_channel<int> &ch_;
  T                           val_;

  bool await_ready() const noexcept { return false; }
  void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> handle) {}
  void await_resume() noexcept {}
};

template <typename T> send_async_awaiter<T> send_async(bidirectional_channel<T> &ch, const T &val) {
  return send_async_awaiter{ch, val};
}
```

`send_async_awaiter` is our awaitable, coroutine friendly type. `send_async` is just what the `send` function would need to be changed into to be awaitable. This code compiles but it doesn't do anything.

I don't want to make this about CSP but I need to go into a little bit of detail about what needs to happen in the channel send function. In this example  I'm using an unbuffered channel which should suspend until there is a ready receiver. Assuming the receiver isn't ready to begin with we need to park the send operation somewhere. To do this we need to only consider `await_ready` and `await_suspend`. `await_ready` is returning false, so the next thing to happen will be `await_suspend`. we get a generic handle to our coroutine that we can use to park it.

The implementation of `bidirectional_channel` that I started out with is based on threads. It uses a mutex and conditional variables to wake up blocked threads but I don't think a `bidirectional_channel_async` type should be implemented in the same way. Instead, I'm going to consider an invasive approach where the suspended coroutine is parked inside the channel. I think this makes sense because this is where I later need to be able to find a parked coroutine to resume when the receiver is ready. It also implies that we could write a completely single threaded CSP library that use cooperative instead of preemptive multithreading. I think adding parallelism to this async CSP library would be easier than going the other way.

I didn't go into all the details of everything here but it's a start. I'm kinda glad that it is decoupled like this because you can build whatever you think is best on top of this.